# Python. Merge columns from different pd tables

Tags: python

There`re two pandas tables: production and sales, which contains columns 'Date', 'Volume' and other. I need to get a separate table, which contains only columns 'Date', 'Volume production', 'Volume sales'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMZrK.png)

Comment: please add sample of input, output and what you've tried yet.

Comment: Your code should be provided as text and not image, so we can reproduce your problem. Please format it as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

column = ['Sales_vol'];

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df1['Sales_volume'], index = pd.to_datetime[df1['Date'], column = column);
new_df.insert(loc=1,column='Production_vol',value=df2['Production_volume']);
```

Hope this helps.